# WPF Bingmaps pushpin event binding mvvm

Tags: wpf, mvvm, bing-maps

I would like to trigger a command in my ViewModel when the pushpin is clicked on the map. How can I achieve this using databinding?

Here is the `DataTemplate` I am using for the pinpoints:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="PushPinTemplate">
    <map:Pushpin Cursor="Hand"
                 map:MapLayer.Position="{Binding Location}">
    </map:Pushpin>
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: Are you familiar with mvvm light?

Comment: I would prefer not using a plugin or framework for solving this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A colleague found the solution:

After adding the Nuget Package `System.Windows.Interactivity.WPF`
and adding the xml namespace

```
xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
```

you can add an `EventTrigger` to the template, here the full template code, where 
`CachePushPinClicked` is an `ICommand`

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="PushPinTemplate">
    <map:Pushpin Cursor="Hand"
                     map:MapLayer.Position="{Binding Location}" >   
     <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseLeftButtonDown">
            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding CachePushPinClicked}"/>
        </i:EventTrigger>
     </i:Interaction.Triggers>
   </map:Pushpin>
</DataTemplate>
```